# Screen turns white after expanding to fullscreen

Tags: java, android, video, webview, fullscreen

While debugging on USB I just wanted to expand WebView to fullscreen. Unfortunately, white screen appeared and nothing after it. I really do not know what to do. I made CustomView and everything seemed fine. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       filmkey = "<iframe width=\"96%\" height=\"96%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/EtMOgsWEAmQ\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

        screen=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        screen.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String myvideokey = filmkey;
        screen.loadData(myvideokey, "text/html", "utf-8");
        screen.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
                super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
            }

            @Override
            public void onHideCustomView() {
                super.onHideCustomView();
            }
        });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try the following Code. In this on full screen i created a `View` which will become full Screen.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            screen.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_support);
        filmkey = "<iframe width=\"96%\" height=\"96%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/EtMOgsWEAmQ\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

        screen=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        screen.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String myvideokey = filmkey;
        screen.loadData(myvideokey, "text/html", "utf-8");
        CustomWebChromeClient custom = new CustomWebChromeClient();
        screen.setWebChromeClient(custom);
    }
```

and the custom `WebChromeClient` is

```
class `CustomWebChromeClient` extends WebChromeClient{


@Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, final CustomViewCallback callback) {
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SupportActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();
    }
}
```

and also make sure you use all these methods in the activity to handle with the data in `webView`.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        screen.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        screen.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        screen.stopLoading();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        screen.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        screen.saveState(outState);
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: "Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SupportActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);" An error appears here which underlines "SupportActivity.this" ("WatchingActivity.this" in my situation) saying "WatchingActivity is not an enclosing class"

Comment: make the class in the watchingActivity only then this errot will not come. All the aforesaid code is in one file only WatchinActivity in your case

Comment: It still appears

Comment: I  am terribly sorry it does not appear now:)